# Viewport Selectors for jQuery fail in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, viewport

The amazing plugin "Viewport Selectors for Jquery" (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) works, but its a old project that seems abandoned by the author.
Example of use:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  $("#mydiv:in-viewport").each(function() {
      $(this).css('background-color','red');
  });
});
```

Works on IE9+, Chrome and fail in IE8-, crash IE on scroll page.

Any tip to solve this? Or just disable viewport detect, ie, always visible...

Tnks so much!

Comment: I don't see where you are even using the viewport plugin above.

Comment: @KevinB fixed example, but just try to see the demo http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport/3x2.html in ie8.